# Reading continuous data from Serial Port using QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, port

I am new for QT C++ and am trying to write a program, which could continuous read data from Serial Port. My Program works sometimes smoothly but sometimes it read the wrong data. I have run debug and here is what I got:

```
"61\x00\x00"
"61\x00\x00"
"61\x00\x00"
"62\x00\x00"
"62\x00\x00"
"62\x00\x00"
"62\x00\x00"
"63\x00\x00"
"63\x00\x00"
"5"
"3\x00\x00"
"5"
"2\x00\x00"
"5"
"2\x00\x00"

"54\x00\x00"
"54\x00\x00"
"54\x00\x00"
"55\x00\x00"
"54\x00\x00"
"54\x00\x00"
"55\x00\x00"
"55\x00\x00"
"5"
"1\x00\x00"
"51"
"\x00\x00"
"5"
"2\x00\x00"
"5"
"1\x00\x00"
"5"
"1\x00\x00"
```

Someway QTSerialPort didn't read all data. And here is my code, where data should be read and display.

```
   if(serial->isOpen() && serial->isReadable()){
       QByteArray receivedData;
       receivedData = serial->readAll();
       qDebug()<<receivedData;
       ui->lcdDistance->display(receivedData.toInt());
    }else{
       QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Doesn't receive data"));
    }
```

I think the problem came from QT, not the microcontroller because I also run debug with my microcontroller and it worked very well.

Here is the code in my uC STM32

```
    while (1) {
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rxData, 1, 1000);

    if (rxData[0] == '1') { //RUN
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, SET);

        lcd_clear();
        lcd_put_cur(0, 0);
        lcd_send_string("LOADING...");

        HAL_Delay(1000);

        lcd_clear();

        int i = 40;

        //HAL_Delay(1000);

        while (i < 100) {
            htim2.Instance->CCR1 = i;
            sensor_time = hcsr04_read();
            distance = sensor_time * .034 / 2;

            sprintf(str_distance,"%lu", distance);

            lcd_clear();
            lcd_put_cur(1, 0);
            lcd_send_string(str_distance);

            sendDistanceStatus = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, str_distance, sizeof(str_distance),
                    100);
            if (sendDistanceStatus == HAL_OK) {
                i++;
                HAL_Delay(300);
            }
        }

        HAL_Delay(1000);
    } else { //STOP
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, RESET);
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_put_cur(0, 0);
        lcd_send_string("STOP...");
    }

}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data read from a serial port is just a stream of bytes.  There's no guarantee all bytes written by a single `write` call at one end will be read by a single `read` call at the other.

Comment: You could show the code that your uC uses to send the data.

Comment: @G.M. I am so curious. How do the Computer read data from Serial Port directly and correctly? Or there is another way? Please give me some advice.

Comment: @eyllanesc I also add the code in my uC. But I think the problem doesn't come from uC

Comment: @eyllanesc do you mean, there is no way to avoid this problem?

Comment: @AnhTu Yes there is a way: Establish basic synchronization rules, for example establish a header, then the number of bytes of the information and finally the raw data and then a code that verifies if the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the synchronization of the information since it cannot be detected when the information starts and ends. A simple solution is to use a character like the endline(`\n`):

```cpp
sprintf(str_distance,"%lu\n", distance);
```

```
if(serial->isOpen() && serial->isReadable()){
    while(serial->canReadLine()){
        QByteArray ba = serial->readLine();
        ba = ba.replace('\0', QByteArray());
        qDebug() << ba;
        ui->lcdDistance->display(ba.toInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I thought about your solution at the beginning but it doesn't work with my case. Here is what I got after running your solution 
"\x00""57\n"
"\x00""125\n"
"125\n"
"125\n"
"51\n"
"\x00""50\n"
"\x00""50\n"
"\x00""51\n"
"\x00""50\n"

Comment: My friend, I tried your update and it gave me something better but doesn't work smoothly
"126\n"
"126\n"
"1"
"25\n"
"74\n"
"55\n"
""
"54\n"
""
"55\n"
""
"55\n"
""
"55\n"
""
"55\n"
""
"55\n"
""
"56"
"\n"
"170\n"

Comment: @AnhTu Why doesn't it work well? When you say that something is not working well then you must be specific: I expect X but with the code it gives Y, etc.

Comment: For example, I expected to get "125\n" but I got "1" "25\n"

Comment: @AnhTu Strange that, how have you declared "str_distance"? what is the distance of `distance` variable?

Comment: the str_distance is defined. char str_distance[4]; Theoretically it could be to 200 (~2meter) .